# How to handle multiple answers by the same user recommending to use a particular different software package instead?

Tags: discussion, answers, not-an-answer

What is the most appropriate response to an answer which essentially says, “Don’t use the software product you’re trying to use, use [something other product].”? Is a simple downvote and comment good enough?

Eg, a user posts a question asking about using [tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tomcat) but the bulk of the answer (or its entirety) is a suggestion to use [jetty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jetty) instead.

What if a user replies to many, eg, [tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tomcat) questions and always says, essentially, “use [jetty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jetty)”?

A follow-up question: If I subscribe to a tag, and notice a user doing this, and downvote their answers, won’t my downvotes be reversed?

Comment: If such answers contain little more than a recommendation to use another software, then yes, that's just opinion-based *tag rot*. Just downvote those. If there's no explanation or reasoned comparison beyond that, it's merely dragging a question off-topic.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If the answer is well-reasoned, shows how to do it in $other in a clear and in every respect superior way, and doing it in $given was at most incidental to the question, what's wrong with it?
(Not saying I remotely believe that user didn't fail those standards.)
What about the users other contributions? If there's evidence he's poisoning the well to get his own (or affiliated) product ahead, that *might* be something to inform the moderators about (a concise but detailed other-flag on one of his answers), who can probably better look into it.

Regarding downvoting them all, just don't search them out to downvote (avoid targeting the user), take all the answers (and the question) of any post you organically come across at it's own merits, and you shouldn't have any concerning spree of downvotes against any one user.

Also, do those posts look like answers? Otherwise, flag as Not An Answer (NAA).

Do they look like answers, but not to that question even considering XY-problem? That might be an other-flag with concise but complete reasoning asking for removal.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I didn't mention it, but I am thinking more of the case where no information on _how_ to accomplish the task in $other was given, just the vague suggestion that it would be somehow _better_ using $other, even though the question was specifically about $given. (That's actually a very useful test, thank you.)

I also am not planning to seek out previous answers, etc, but as a subscriber to a particular tag, I expect to have a lot of visibility to new answers in this tag.

Comment: Is this saying it's okay to post an answer to a question about how to do something in some given language (e.g. reading from a file in C++) recommending doing it in a completely different language (e.g. Python)? That does not sound good at all. Or is there something about the specific tags in the question which makes this different?

Comment: I guess it would depend on how much locked into the specific technology the question looks like. To me, something along the lines of _“to do X, I picked technology Y and now I'm stuck on that issue”_ can be helpfuly answered by explaining how to do X with another technology, because it's likely the asker can switch. On the other hand, _“I am working on a large project using technology X”_ is probably a sign that a technology switch is not a reasonable option and such an answer won't be helpful.

Comment: @spectras We should treat answers like they're going to be seen by others with the same or a similar issue. Just because the person that asked the question is locked into a particular technology/product doesn't mean that others that come along in the future will also be locked in.